# Ошибка в работе php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Пытаюсь запустить сервис.

при попытке входа на главную страницу вижу:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/SP/Gear/Dispatch.php on line 107

В логах *nginx*:

> error] 22450#0: *43 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/SP/Gear/Dispatch.php on line 107" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.91.216, server: front.lo, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.91.10"

Привожу свой *virtualhost*:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/front/www;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_boltest.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_boltest.log;

    # favicon off
    location /favicon.ico { }

    # main location
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
    }

    # javascript location
    location /js/ {
        root /var/www/front/www/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
    }

    # style location
    location /css/ {
        root /var/www/front/www/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
    }

    # image location
    location /images/ {
        root /var/www/front/www/;
    }

    # the main entry point
    location @router {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }


    # simple config for php
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 90; #300;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

вот строка из файла:

```
foreach ($sets->hosts[$host] as $key => $value) {
```

После изменений мой хост выглядит так.

```
 server {

        listen 80;

        server_name front admin.lo;





        root /var/www/front/www;



        index index.php index.html index.htm;



        access_log /var/log/nginx/front_access.log;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/front_error.log;



        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ @router;

        }



        location /js/ {

                root /var/www/front/www/;

                try_files $uri $uri/ @router;

        }



        location /css/ {

                root /var/www/front/www/;

        }



        location @router {

                rewrite ^ /index.php last;

        }



        #include /etc/nginx/templates/php;



        location ~ \.php$ {

                #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

                fastcgi_read_timeout 90; #300;

                fastcgi_index index.php;

                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

                include fastcgi_params;

        }

}
```

Comment: *php-fpm* тут ни при чём – просто ошибка в коде php. Посмотрите значение `$sets->hosts[$host]`: там явно не массив оказался.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Посмотрю отпишусь.

Comment: вот код из php файла.  foreach ($sets->hosts[$host] as $key => $value) {
            $conf->addAttr($key, $value);
        }
Подскажите что тут может быть не так.

Comment: Если заменить foreach на is_arrey ошибка в браузере пропадает, и я вижу пустую страницу. а в логах вижу FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS)

Comment: проблема в значении, которое приходит в `$sets`

Comment: Раобрался. Дело было не в PHP. Дело было в неправельном виртуалхосте. И добавлением хостов в файл хостс /etc/hosts.